# Project needs to clean again and again?

Tags: android

I am using 2.1 platform. When I start a project the R.java file has not seen in the gen folder.I use the below steps,if the first step not correct the error I will go to second and so on.

1. Clean the project, uncheck the option Build Automatically and Rebuild it.
2. Import Android.R;

3.Import Package.R;

I know these steps only.But the error still remains.I have to Clean each project when I create it always.In some times this issue will happens after complete the code, on that time I have to re-edit the code and make the code as shown at the begining [ have only **Oncreate** method] and clean the project and rebuilt it and copy the code and run the project.After cleaning the project no problem.This issue came within 1 month.Is any way to add the **R.java** file to gen folder when I create a project ?

Comment: Check `Build automatically` right below the `Clean...`.

Comment: No change , the error still remains.When I create the project it has no R.java file.What is the Actual problem ?

Comment: check your problems tab it will show the error. possible you may add any image with caps or numeric chars rename it or may be you layout file ids or something is missing.

Comment: Yes, on problems tab I see the error " Invalid resourse directory name".........Resource is aaa......also I saved an image to drawable hdpi  iii.jpeg........how to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logcat, that will show you the error, may be there are spaces in drawable for example image_xyx.png

Comment: Have you seen the problems console as well

Comment: LogCat and Console are Empty now